# Retrieve data from server and operate a GUI

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to know if this is possible using VBA, if it is possible, I will try to code it and if not I should look for another platform where it is possible.
Let me explain:

We have 1 main excel file. There`s a header name and a bunch of different values and settings we need to use.

1. We have a online server where the code has to look for the header name and just click on the name. This will automatically download to the download folder and we can copy this file in the same folder as the main excel file. There is no search function inside the online server. It is just a webpage where there is a list of names.
2. Inside the downloaded file is an xml file that we can open with notepad and we need to compare the settings inside the notepad with the settings from the main excel file (this I know it can be coded)
3. Then a GUI has to be opened (we dont have access to the server behind it), it should fill in the header name in the textbox from the GUI, click upload and then it should save it in the same folder as the main excel.
4. we also need to move a lot of folder based on the info from the main file but this is also basic coding.

Since Im quite new with the VBA coding, I only wish to know if this is possible in excel. I dont want to wast time searching for codes and then realize it is not possible , especially with the GUI operating.

Comment: #3 will be the main challenge.  You might consider something like this - https://www.amarindaz.com/autoit-in-excel-vba_17/  Everything else is possible in "regular" VBA.

Comment: In step 1 it seems like the user starts by logging into some existing on-line server which already presents a list of header names. Which causes a file to appear in the download folder.  How does the user determine the specific filename from the many files that appear there from many users doing the same thing?  What is they select the wrong file???  And process yesterdays file twice??

Comment: @donPablo yes, you are exactly right! This is a problem that we need to tackle. The header names are unique for 90% lets say, so for the other 10%, we will need to code an extra check. If you have any ideas, let me know. I am currently finishing step 2.